# Creating 3 level subquery Propel

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, propel

Hi guys I would like to ask if anyone of you know how to create a select statement in propel using a 3 level subquery... Initially I have this query and it works fine but I want it to be more like propel type... can anyone help me with this?

Here's my query

```
select c.*, count(d.id) as like_count from (
    select a.*, count(b.id) as points_count
    from (
        select * 
        from reviews 
        where user_id ='3') a 
    left join points as b on (a.id = b.type_id) 
    where b.type='review'
    group by a.id 
    order by a.created desc) c left join `like` d on (c.id = d.type_id) group by c.id
```

Here's what I have so far but just from the 2 level subquery the output query is not right

```
$review = ReviewsQuery::create()->filterByUserId($user_id);
$points = PointsQuery::create('b')
        ->withColumn("COUNT(b.Id)", 'points_count')
        ->addSelectQuery($review, 'a', true)
        ->toString(); // This is just to check what will be the query output
```

Can anyone help me with this please

Answer (score 1):

I've not done what you need to do before and always presumed when I would need to run complex queries such as yours, I would just get Propel to run a custom query.

This might not be the appropriate way to do it, but thought I'd point it out just in case it wasn't something you'd seen.  There's a description on how to do it on this page about half way down: http://propelorm.org/documentation/03-basic-crud.html

Comment: Actually i need a more complex one. I have a simple query I made its working about 1 1/2 way through the 3 level subquery I'll update my question

Answer (score 0):

You can anidate subqueries by:

__LEVEL 1

```
$c1 = new ReviewsQuery();//First query
$c1->addSelfSelectColumns();//implement all columns
$c1->filterByUserId(3);//the where clause --where user_id ='3'--
```

__Level 2

```
$s1 = new ReviewsQuery();//Second Level 
$s1->addSelectQuery($c1,"a"); // Implements first query
$s1->addAlias("b",PointsTableMap::COL_TYPE_ID); //prepare Join
$s1->addJoin("a.Id",PointsTableMap::alias("b",PointsTableMap::COL_TYPE_ID))//Add the join
$s1->where(PointsTableMap::alias("b",PointsTableMap::COL_TYPE)."=?",'review')//filter by -- where b.type='review' --
```

(... group by...select...etc ...)

__LEVEL 3

```
$c3 = new ReviewsQuery();//The high level Query
$c3->addSelectQuery($s1,"c");//adding a subquery as "c" 
$c3->addJoin... //continue as a normal Query Object
```

Be care whith namespaces... there are some bugs working whith that in Propel2